# Find a byte offset in a .NET Assembly

Tags: .net

I'm trying to debug an error that the client has reported to us. The stacktrace only has byte offsets, not line numbers.

e.g.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      Foo.Bar(FooFoo p) +32
>      Foo.BarBar() +191
>      Foo.BarBarBar() +15

How can I reverse engineer these byte offsets into lines of code / method calls etc?

How can I find where the NullReferenceException is being thrown?

Comment: in future you can ship application with debug symbols, this will produce lines, not offset in stack trace

Comment: Not very easily if you compiled with optimizations enabled.

Comment: +1 on that. THer is no reason to have debug symbolos NOT compiled. Even if not shipping live, this way you could send them over to the client.

Comment: @Cody Gray disagree. it is not just switching Debug <-> Release. PDB generation can be set alongside with optimization, they do not interfere each other.

Comment: @TomTom you can ship without them, but when crash happens you can ship symbols and ask to reproduce.

Comment: @Andrey: It wasn't a response to your comment.

Comment: @Cody Gray may be. i was just saying that optimization is not a serious problem.

Comment: Thanks for the heated debate guys

Comment: @Andrey: Optimized code *is* a serious problem for someone trying to reverse engineer byte offsets into lines of code without PDB symbols. It means you can't make *any* assumptions that there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the IL and your source. I don't see anywhere you've disagreed with that so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution that might work (or may be not :) ). The problem is that the mapping between offset and line numbers is contained in pdb (aka the debug symbols)

1. Take exactly (important) same build configuration as the one that was used to ship binaries to client. Then go to project properties, tab "Build", click button "Advanced" on the bottom of the page. Then find "Debug Info" and select "pdb-only"
2. Build the project and go to output folder.
3. Pick `ildasm`, either add it to `PATH` or copy it somewhere.
4. In your build folder do `ildasm /LINENUM /SOURCE YourFile.exe`. It will output IL with offset and source line mapping.

The only problem that I see that you will not be able to produce *exactly* same binaries and mapping might fluctate.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your project in visual studio
2. Put breakpoint on Foo.Bar(FooFoo p)
3. Compile and start debugging. Do action that will invoke Foo.Bar(FooFoo p). Note that you need to use configuration that was used to produce client assembly (because of optimization) and of course same source code
4. Open Call Stack window, right click and enable "Show byte offsets" and disable "Show line numbers"
5. Step through function until you hit something like "MyAssembly.dll!MyProject.Something.Foo.Bar(FooFoo p) + 0x32 bytes" (or "+ 0x20 bytes" if your offset decimal number)
6. Win

Edit: Andreys solution is probably better tho :)

Answer (score 3):

The only tool I can remember off the top of my head would be the [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Open the exactly same binary as your client has in it, and change the language in the Options dialog into IL, and it should show (AFAIK) the same byte offsets as labels on each line.

You'll have to read IL instead of C# or anything though, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: this will not work. Reflector reconstruct c#, it doesn't present the formatting. if you have empty lines in your source reflector won't reproduce them.

Comment: @Andrey: Did you miss the part of the answer where he says "you'll have to read IL instead of C#...but it's better than nothing"?

Comment: @Andrey Reflector can show the IL - I'n not sure what your point is re. C#?

Comment: @chibacity it is point of author of question. he wants to map IL offset to source line numbers.

Comment: @chibacity btw if you want just IL you can use `ildasm` which comes with sdk.

Comment: @Cody Gray yes, i missed that point. But if you want to look at il `ildasm` is fine. and it can map lines if you have pdbs.

Comment: @Andrey I know about `ildasm`. You don't have to talk up your answer in comments to another answer, we can all read the answers...