# Need Help to find source code line from stack trace byte offset

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

can any one tell me how to find the source code line using byte offset (from stack trace) in wp7?

Comment: ...and are you trying to do this on the phone, or analysing a crash dump?

Comment: got stack trace from APP HUB which has byte offset. I am trying to find the line which caused the crash.                                                          XXX.fullprofile.FullProfile_Pivot.horoicon_clicked    224   here 224 is byteoffset but what i need is line number. I am trying to find this in phone

Comment: Have you the PDBs for the exact version the crash dump is for?

Comment: Same problem here; I do have the PDB. How do they help?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886191/find-a-byte-offset-in-a-net-assembly

Comment: Those offsets are not IL byte offsets (as displayed by ILDASM); seems like they're byte offsets in JIT-compiled native code.

Answer (score 0):

This is something Ive used but its not win phone specific - but it might work for you with some tweeking:

```
private static string lineAndMethod() {
    int stack_frame_depth = 5;
    StackFrame sf = new StackFrame(stack_frame_depth, true);
    while (sf.GetFileName() == null && stack_frame_depth > 0)
    sf = new StackFrame(--stack_frame_depth, true);
    if (sf.GetFileName() == null) // Failed.
        return "";
    MethodBase mb_caller = sf.GetMethod();
    retrun string.Format("{0}, {1}: {2}]",
                         Path.GetFileName(sf.GetFileName()),
                         mb_caller.Name, sf.GetFileLineNumber());
}
```