# NullReferenceException vs. MSIL

Tags: c#, windows-phone, .net-assembly, cil

I'm interpreting an exception report from a C# Windows Phone app. A method throws a `NullReferenceException`. The method goes:

```
public void OnDelete(object o, EventArgs a)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(Res.IDS_AREYOUSURE, Res.IDS_APPTITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        m_Field.RequestDelete();
}
```

It's consistent with `m_Field` being null - there's simply nothing else there that can possibly be null. But here's the mysterious part.

The `GetILOffset()` from the `StackFrame` from the `StackTrace` for the exception object returns 0x13. The MSIL for the method, as shown by ILDASM, goes:

```
IL_0000:  call       string App.Res::get_IDS_AREYOUSURE()
IL_0005:  call       string App.Res::get_IDS_APPTITLE()
IL_000a:  ldc.i4.1
IL_000b:  call       valuetype (...) System.Windows.MessageBox::Show(...)
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0011:  bne.un.s   IL_001e
IL_0013:  ldarg.0
IL_0014:  ldfld      class App.Class2 App.Class1::m_Field
IL_0019:  callvirt   instance void App.Class2::RequestDelete()
IL_001e:  ret
```

Here's what I don't understand. If the offset is indeed 0x13, that means the `ldarg` line causes the exception. But the command is documented as not throwing any exceptions. It's `callvirt` that should throw, isn't it? Or is the offset relative to something other than the method beginning? `ldfld` can also throw, but only if the `this` object is null; that's not possible in C# AFAIK.

The docs mention that debug info might get in the way of the offset, but it's a release build.

The DLL that I'm examining with ILDASM is exactly the one that I've shipped to the Windows Phone Store as a part of my XAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the JIT generates the machine code, it also generates MSIL <--> machine code mappings. When you get an exception in the generated code, the run-time will use the mappings to identify the IL offset.

The JIT is allowed to re-order machine instructions as part of its optimizations (when they are enabled), this can result in mappings becoming more approximate and granular. If the field access was brought forward (memory access is relatively slow, sometimes its good to start loading it well before you need it) then the exception may appear to have been thrown by an earlier IL instruction.

---

I butchered one of my debug utilities to do the following:

- start a target process and run until there is an exception
- capture the IL bytes & IL-to-native mappings
- (crudely) disassemble the IL with indicators showing which IL instructions are grouped together with the same mapping.

I then ran the tool on a dummy process that does roughly what you show in the question, and got the following (release build):

```
IL_0000: call 0600000B
IL_0005: call 0600000A
IL_000A: ldc.i4.1
IL_000B: call 0A000014
IL_0010: ldc.i4.1
IL_0011: bne.un.s 30
----
IL_0013: ldarg.0
IL_0014: ldfld 04000001
IL_0019: callvirt 06000004
----
IL_001E: ret
```

As you can see, the `ldarg.0`, `ldfld` and `callvirt` instructions are all covered by the same mapping, so if any of these triggers an exception, they will all map back to the same IL offset (0x13).

Comment: But it's not the field access (`ldfld`) that should throw (since `this` is not `null`), it's the `callvirt`. And looking at disassembly, I don't think reordering is the cause here.

Comment: Fair point on field access/reordering, but I still think it can be explained by reduced granularity in the mappings. I'll double check the actual mappings and get back with the results.

Comment: @svick, I reproduced, checked the mappings and updated with the results.

Comment: Good find. Oh well. By the way, how can one see the MSIL-to-native mappings (either in run time or offline using a copy of the DLL)? If the best crash location pointer we can get is a MSIL range, I'd like to see those.

Comment: The mappings won't exist until the native code is generated, which generally means you need to extract it from a running process or memory dump (you might be able to extract it directly from ngen'ed images but I never looked into it). To get these mappings I used the the managed debugger api and [GetILToNativeMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232113%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in particular. The same thing is also available through the [profiler api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231275%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hm, I'll see what can be done... It's on a phone, ngen is not available there, and [crossgen is uncooperative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345747/generating-arm-code-for-a-managed-assembly-on-an-intel-machine).