# How to get IL instruction offset when exception happens?

Tags: c#, cil

I want to get IL instruction offset when exception happens (from the start of the method).

For example I have object initializer:

```
var obj = new SomeObject {
   F1 = something.A,
   F2 = something.B,
   F3 = something.C,
   F4 = something2.A,
   F5 = something.D
};
```

If `something2` will be `null` - exception will get thrown.

Exception stack trace will be pointed at first line:

```
var obj = new SomeObject {
```

Can I get exact IL code offset to the problematic object?

In this example I'd like to get offset to this instruction:

```
callvirt instance void SomeClass2::get_A(class SomeClass2)
```

Update: answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886191/find-a-byte-offset-in-a-net-assembly) (via PDB) not gonna work in this situation as line will point exactly at the same place.

Comment: If you break on exception, you might be able to create a [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getiloffset?view=netframework-4.8) object in the watch window, passing the exception into its constructor and calling `GetILOffset()` on the first frame (something like `new StackTrace($exception).GetFrame(0).GetILOffset()` IIRC). Having said that the JIT might end up mapping all generated native code for that statement to the same IL offset, in which case there isn't much you can do except to break up the statement.

Comment: @BrianReichle Your answer really worked like I'd wanted! You have to create an answer so I can check it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break on exception, you might be able to create a [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) object in the watch window, passing the exception into its constructor and calling `GetILOffset()` on the first frame (something like `new StackTrace($exception).GetFrame(0).GetILOffset()` IIRC).

Having said that, the JIT may end up mapping all the generated native code for that statement to the same IL offset, in which case there isn't much you can do except to break up the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it solves your problem exactly, but if you use `ildasm` to get the IL listing for the assembly, then you can reconstitute the assembly and generate a new .pdb using: `ilasm /PDB /DEBUG ...` (the assembly ought to be functionally equivalent to the original, though not byte-for-byte identical).

The interesting thing about this process is that the .pdb that's generated treats the IL listing as the "source", so as long as your IDE can find the .pdb and the IL listing, you can step through the IL instruction by instruction in the same way you'd step through ordinary C#, and you'll also see exceptions on the IL instruction they occur (even for property initializers as in your example).

Comment: Wow, that's helpful! But it doesn't solve my problem. My exact problem is that exceptions happen on remote server that I doesn't have direct access to. So I wanted better debugging info. Thanks for replying, I will remember this.